# how mount the external hard drive with LVM2_member error ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: mount, lvm

I made a mistake and delete the lv from my external hard disk.I don't know that how I can create new lv and mount my hard.I have no access to my data on the hard disk.

```
payamzowghi@payamzowghi:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /media/payamzowghi/mount/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lvm2` ?